# animated gif in array in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, optimization, gif, animated

I am trying to use optimize:false  parameter in my code to use animated gif as a mouseover:

```
var icon1 = "circle.png";
var icon2 = "circlered.gif";


var markers = [];
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: map,
  visible: false,
  icon: icon1
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
  return function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    marker.setIcon(icon2);
  }
})(marker, i));
markers.push(marker); // save all markers

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker) {
  return function(evt) {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setIcon(icon1);
  }
})(marker));
```

when I use  for example:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    visible: false,
    icon: icon2, //here I purposely changed it to animated gif first
    optimize: false
    });
```

I have no problems.
but when I try to use the same here:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    marker.setIcon(icon2);
optimize:false;// here is the wrong code obviously 
  }
})(marker, i));
```

I get the image disappearing not animating
Please suggest solution

**based on the suggestions posted by the @geocoder here:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <style>
html, 
body,

#map-canvas{
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    height: 880px;
    z-index:2
    }
#maptwo {
    z-index:1
}
    </style>    

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.222869, 47.602673),
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});
var icon1 = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png";
var icon2 = {
url: "http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-01-35/e8nZC.gif",
scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(75, 100)
};



var markers = [];
var marker, i;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: map,
  optimized: false,
  visible: false,
  icon: icon1
});
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition())
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
  return function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    marker.setIcon(icon2);
  }
})(marker, i));
markers.push(marker); // save all markers

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker) {
  return function(evt) {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setIcon(icon1);
  }
})(marker));
/* Change markers on zoom */
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
var zoom = map.getZoom();
// iterate over markers and call setVisible
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setVisible(zoom >= 11);
}
});     

  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var locations = [
['Location1', 39.031586, 46.590031, 5],
['Location2', 38.998439, 46.557591, 4],
['Location3', 38.913429, 46.547370, 3],
['Location4', 39.090245, 46.703794, 2],
['Location5', 39.130588, 46.696239, 1]
  ];
//here I create a function that will show/hide layers that are defined by the  latLng  values  
function toggleLayer(firLayer, id) {
  if ($('#' + id).is(':checked')) {
firLayer.setMap(map);
  } else {
firLayer.setMap(null);
  }
}
//this is the end of the function

// Fir AZE is one of the many layers that are drawn
        drawAZE = new google.maps.Polygon({
            path: firAZE,
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#00CCFF',
            fillOpacity: 0.15
        }); 
//end of FirAZE  end of layer
// Add a listener for the drawAZE mouseover/mouseout event.
google.maps.event.addListener(drawAZE ,'mouseover',function(){
this.setOptions({fillColor: "#FF0000"},{fillOpacity:"0.8"});
}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(drawAZE ,'mouseout',function(){
this.setOptions({fillColor: "#00CCFF"},{fillOpacity:"0.5"});
});
//end of drawAZE listener


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="maptwo"></div>
<input id="fir_azerbaijan" type="checkbox" onClick="toggleLayer(drawAZE,'fir_azerbaijan')" /> AZERBAIJAN
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the code in     "Fir AZE" draws a layer.
then later it(the drawn layer) is supposed to be shown on click , the example provided initially at this link www.visualguide.ca/example shows that.
when I was asking about the solution for the animated marker I thought that I had problem with optimize :false - because all their lines of code were working ok.
as I have tried to implement solution provided below it worked! but I lost my ability to show/hide layers on click.sorry if this was not clear initially

my intial code was:

```
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 8,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.222869, 47.602673),
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
 zIndex: 3
  };

// Set map    
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
```

it was changed to

```
 function initialize() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(
 document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.222869, 47.602673),
   zoom: 13,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 });

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: map,
  optimized: false,
  visible: false,
  icon: icon1
});
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition())
//....
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

I have compared line by line to locate this, and am stumbled.

Comment: Are you getting javascript errors reported in the console?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue

Comment: here it is:
http://www.visualguide.ca/example.html

either zoom to the bottom of the Azerbaijan republic, or

select zangilan area by clicking and then zoom  till you see the markers then move mouse over.complete example is the html source

Comment: I don't know what has happened but somehow the mail file was deleted, I re-uploaded it

Comment: main file, example.html

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: infowindow is not defined`

Comment: I get a javascript error with your updated code `Uncaught ReferenceError: firAZE is not defined`

Comment: By the way, the layers stopping working should be a new question if my answer addressed your original question.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create the marker with `{optimized: false}`:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    optimized: false,
    icon: icon1
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function(evt) {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      marker.setIcon(icon2);
    }
  })(marker, i));
  markers.push(marker); // save all markers

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker) {
    return function(evt) {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setIcon(icon1);
    }
  })(marker));
}
```

**code snippet with animated gif:**

```js
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var icon1 = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png";
  var icon2 = {
    url: "http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-01-35/e8nZC.gif",
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(75, 100)
  };


  var markers = [];
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      optimized: false,
      icon: icon1
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition())
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
      return function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.setIcon(icon2);
      }
    })(marker, i));
    markers.push(marker); // save all markers

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker) {
      return function(evt) {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setIcon(icon1);
      }
    })(marker));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var locations = [
  ['palace', 52.231871, 21.005841],
  ['arkadia', 52.257305, 20.984481],
  ['stadium', 52.215147, 21.035074]
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: hi, I see it working in the run code snippet, but I have two questions:

what does the var geocoder; do?

and I seem not to be able to replicate it.tomorrow morning I will show why

Comment: `geocoder` is not used, removed it from the code snippet

Comment: ok, I just tested it, it works with one huge problem, none of my layers are showing... I guess the problem is with the code you used for bounds??

Comment: What layers?  There aren't any in your question.  I doubt it has anything to do with the bounds stuff, you don't need that in your code.  You didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I had to add code to make the posted code work, therefore my answer will not be something you can just paste into your page without accounting for those possible differences, but it demonstrates it can be done starting with the code you did post.

Comment: hi, @geocoder,

I thought I provided the minimal or complete in the example file?
in this file

[link](http://www.visualguide.ca/example.html)
if you look at the source it has all indents, explanations etc.was this that was asked for?

Comment: I get what you are saying about copy-paste etc, my issue is that I am a real novice in this and while building I am trying to learn  :)

Comment: Did you read the link regarding MVCEs?  Questions should be complete without referencing external links, particularly those in comments.  I answered based on the information provided in the question.

Comment: hi, @geocoder, I am in NO WAY blaming you here :)please don't get that impression.
My page would have been 24 thousands lines of code if I was to post according to MVCe etc , the question was complete witht he amount of information we discussed.
the problem I have is with the using the bounds and mapOptions as together they somehow stop my layers from appearing.

Comment: Then don't use them, all the bounds stuff does is center the map on the data in the markers.

Comment: I need to use the region boundaries shown on click, that is the project requirement: .
1.onclick each shown layer of the region boundary
2.on zoom change the markers are shown
3. on mouse over the animation pulsates, the infowindow appears
4. on click the infowindow stays on the screen and is selectable
this is the scope :)

Comment: All that is great, but doesn't relate to your original question which was "I am trying to use optimize:false parameter in my code to use animated gif as a mouseover" and it isn't working...

Comment: I gracefully disagree, but, can we please try to solve my issue?

Comment: As I said earlier, that is out of scope for this answer. Your new problem is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

somehow I have managed(with the help of geocoder and Alex - thanks

```
//announce my variables
var icon1 = "circle.png";
var icon2 = "circlered.gif";


var markers = [];
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: map,
  optimized:false, // <-- required for animated gif
  visible: false,
  icon: icon1
});
```

I also managed to have my layers appearing on click